# Accessing the variable created by using attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to understand what `attr_accessor` gives me access to. From what I understand, it provides getter and setter methods. So `attr_accessor :color` it will create something like the following for me

```
def color
  @color
end

def color=(value)
  @color = value
end
```

The thing I don't understand is why in the following code, why can't I use `color=` in my initializer? (it ends up being blank). Why do I need to use `@color=` or `self.color=` instead? Shouldn't `color=` be a way to call the setter method that was just created for me above?

```
class Bird
  attr_accessor :color
  def initialize(c="green")
    color = c  # this doesn't work
    # either one of the following DOES work
    # @color = c
    # self.color = c
  end
end

puts Bird.new.color  # prints nothing unless using @color or self.color
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An expression like `color = "green"` assigns `"green"` to a local variable, *not* to an attribute. Attribute setters *always* need a  receiver, even if the receiver is `self`.

Comment: a related question, is `self.color` the way to go or `@color`?

Comment: @Dty, a very good question. I would say that in the class implementation itself, using `@color` is fine. However, in included modules and any child classes, I would advise against using `@color` directly (instead using `color` or `self.color`, and `self.color=`). Using instance variables in derived classes or included modules violates encapsulation, even though Ruby will happily let you.

Comment: Something I recently found out is that you should use `self.color` if you have a setter method that you want to run. Using `@self.color` would bypass the setter method.